# Difference between using typeof for type parameter in a generic vs. without

Tags: typescript

In TypeScript, what's the difference between using

```
InstanceType<typeof UserManager>
```

and

```
InstanceType<UserManager>
```

I've taken a look at TS' [typeof](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/typeof-types.html). Is `SomeGeneric<typeof UserManager>` really a more general typing? i.e. We can reduce `typeof UserManager` to something like `Function` so that it's effectively `InstanceType<Function>`?

Comment: Is `UserManager` a class? If so, your second snippet is not valid. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOBZMA7MBzZ0DeAvgLABQpALgJ4AOC0AgtALzQCS6E5GwCAKjQgA8VWgHsAZnESoM2ZAD4KA6ACFmbDl3Q9+tQfGRpMOJIpJA So I am having a hard time understand what you mean in this question.

Comment: We need to see the declaration(s) of `UserManager` to know for sure. In general, `typeof` is used to extract the type from a real JS entity (when used in a TS context).

Comment: This was the usage: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOBZMA7MBzZ0DeAsAFDTSYC2CAXNBAC5ICW6WA3MaRAK5IXW0NmbYh2jAA9unpIuwOuKQAKLoiQ08ZMJRrShrWjz47BLaAF8AlPlGk6AC0YQAdH2gBeaCuQutCdiVJoe0cnbl5fd09VUMNff1IzYkSiYjoATwAHBDhVNBZkAEkpOgxgBAAVTOyPIvpSiqqAHnSs8QAzHOQ87GQAPn8AegGgqs7UDBwkWpL0MsqsyOn6+YRG+C6MHqR+6EaAWj3oABNxBAh0AHI6aAB3BQBrESIJYqjkGnXx-Kni5dGPQgBIzQABEAClxHZ0CCADSiMLAkEAEVOsKSrCAA. As a follow-up question, why can't we use a class as the type as opposed having to extract the type in the case of `typeof`?

Comment: You can use a class as a type. What did you try that didn't work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are talking about classes here, since they exist as both a value (the class constructor) and a type.

So because the *value* `UserManager` is the class constructor, then `typeof UserManager` is the type of that constructor. That is the type you would use with the `new` keyword, and has the static methods.

Where the *type* `UserManager` is the interface of instances.

What `InstanceType<T>` does is that it returns the type of instances that a constructor `T` would make. That means that `T` here must be a constructor type to be valid.  Otherwise you'll get a type error:

```
type A = InstanceType<UserManager>
// Type 'UserManager' does not satisfy the constraint 'abstract new (...args: any) => any'.
//  Type 'UserManager' provides no match for the signature 'new (...args: any): any'.(2344)
```

All this means that the type:

```
InstanceType<typeof UserManager>
```

Is identical to the type:

```
UserManager
```

---

> Why can't we use a class as the type as opposed having to extract the type in the case of typeof?

You don't need to at all, unless you only have the type of a constructor. In the snippet you provided in the comments, you can just do:

```
const user: UserManager = {
  name: "John",
  surname: "Doe",
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false#code/MYGwhgzhAECqEFMBOBZMA7MBzZ0DeAsAFDTSYC2CAXNBAC5ICW6WA3MaRAK5IXW0NmbYh2jAA9unpIuwOuKQAKLoiQ08ZMJRrShrWjz47BLaAF8AlPlGk6AC0YQAdH2gBeaCuQutCdiVJoe0cnbl5fd09VUMNff1IzYkSiYgB6VOgAdQUAawhiCSk6KOQaeGQ0TBwkSMIAo2gAIgApcTt0RoAaUTCGxoARcQQupP80jIBBEAhxaAB3XPyiQvoSpAAmMtVK7FwPdAQ5uG2MXaU60gaAcmaMBCvugN7fGivB+8fLIA)

This works because it fulfills the interface contract of an instance of `UserManager`, even if it wasn't constructed by the `UserManager` constructor. So Typescript is happy with it.

---

#### Update:

From [this playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ts=4.3.5#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdhADwAqAfAgN4CwAUAgqJDPAgLa4QAWA9gCYAKAJQAuBADceASz4BuOgF86dFGgwBhLlOR8EUtgAdkuDoQzY8hIgBFgEXBRr12nXoKFUEdBg1g98YDzGAHTIPADmAgDkBlBShAgAZlA8bAia2nxRQrJezkq0BXSJAK748FL+CLHxEGAAYilsAOIEuHGwAgY4BBAAkobGphA8UGIWvUSUCmQeTr7+gSFhkd2W-YMmvaPBHNz8wjmKyrQ1Zo2prfjtUp0ZOke0APRP1XHnTVc3ndcA7ulaB65F4IIgAWjBCF+owA1mAgA) you get this error:

```
Argument of type 'typeof Child' is not assignable to parameter of
type 'Parent<{}>'. Property 'method' is missing in type
'typeof Child' but required in type 'Parent<{}>
```

> "why is the `Child` really `typeof Child`?"

Because the type of every `value` is `typeof value`. And when you use `Child` as value (by passing it as an argument), it has the type `typeof Child`.

Here, the value `Child` is a class constructor function, which is simply a function that can be called with `new` to create instances of `Child`.

> "If I wanted to make this work by passing in just the class Child, how would I go about this?"

In order to execute instance methods on an instance of a class, you must instantiate that class. Your code calls `.method()` which is an instance method, yet no instance is ever created. That's not going to work.

So your question boils down to "How do I use an instance of a class without ever creating an instance of a class?". And the answer is: *you don't.*

Say you have a factory that makes cars. You cannot tell the factory to start the engine, you can only tell that to a car that the factory made. If you have a function that starts a car, you have to tell the factory to make a car, and then provide that car to your function.

```
// The "factory" in the above example
class Car {
  startEngine() {}
}
const aCar: Car = new Car() // what the factory makes.
```

Given that, here's a table:

- Factory (the constructor)

  - value: `Car`
  - type: `typeof Car`
- Car (an instance)

  - value: `new Car()`
  - type: `Car`

So you can either create an instance and provide it to your function:

```
function foo(instance: MyClass){
  instance.someMethod()
}
foo(new MyClass())
```

Or pass the constructor and make an instance in that function:

```
function foo(someClass: typeof MyClass){
  const instance = new someClass()
  instance.someMethod()
}
foo(MyClass)
```

But again, somewhere, somehow, you must build the car to use the car.

Comment: Thanks. As a somewhat related question: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?strictPropertyInitialization=false&ts=4.3.5#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdhADwAqAfAgN4CwAUAgqJDPAgLa4QAWA9gCYAKAJQAuBADceASz4BuOgF86dFGgwBhLlOR8EUtgAdkuDoQzY8hIgBFgEXBRr12nXoKFUEdBg1g98YDzGAHTIPADmAgDkBlBShAgAZlA8bAia2nxRQrJezkq0BXSJAK748FL+CLHxEGAAYilsAOIEuHGwAgY4BBAAkobGphA8UGIWvUSUCmQeTr7+gSFhkd2W-YMmvaPBHNz8wjmKyrQ1Zo2prfjtUp0ZOke0APRP1XHnTVc3ndcA7ulaB65F4IIgAWjBCF+owA1mAgA.

Comment: From the error `Argument of type 'typeof Child' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Parent<{}>'. Property 'method' is missing in type 'typeof Child' but required in type 'Parent<{}>`, why is the `Child` really `typeof Child` which I suppose is why it's breaking because `typeof Child` doesn't have `method` implemented. If I wanted to make this work by passing in just the class `Child`, how would I go about this? And more generally, when we pass in a class as an argument, are we *always* passing in the constructor type as you had mentioned above? i.e. `typeof SomeClass`

Comment: Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks for the updated answer. I think it's mostly clear. I'm still confused by this part: `Property 'method' is missing in type 'typeof Child' but required in type 'Parent<{}>'`. My understanding is that the type `Child` has `method` implemented so in order to get the types to match, we have to use a value whose type has the same implementation as `Parent<{}>`. In this case, it would be an instance of `Child` as the type would then be `Child`, which does have `method` implemented. Is this correct?

Comment: More generally, with classes, we can pass in the constructor function as the value or an instance of the class. This has to be matched with the type on the method parameter. Is the parameter type based on the instance type then? i.e. `Parent<{}>` not `typeof Parent<{}>` as we see in the error: `... required in type 'Parent<{}> `(`typeof Parent<{}>` wouldn't make sense here since it's an abstract class and has no constructor but just theoretically speaking).